# Taking screenshots in Terraria without HUD with one shortcut

Tags: terraria

I often take screenshots in Terraria, but I rarely, if ever, want the HUD to appear in them. In order to do this I need to press use the shortcut to hide the HUD, take the screenshot, and then show the HUD again. This is annoying, especially during boss battles.

Is there any way to take screenshots, excluding the HUD automatically in the process?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [camera mode](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Camera_mode) to take screenshots. Screenshots taken during camera mode will not include UI elements.

Camera mode can also be used to take screenshots regardless of the window size, making it ideal if you have large structures/objects you wish to screenshot.

To enable camera mode, press <kbd>F1</kbd> at any point during gameplay, or select the camera icon next to the housing menu.

To get out of camera mode, either press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or any of the hotbar keys (0-9).